# Multiple maven process concurrent build with shared local repository on CI system

Tags: java, maven, concurrency, continuous-integration, devops

I'm recently building a CI system, where several project will be **build concurrently with shared local repository**. And several error occurs.

To find solution and make it simple, I wrote a script to **simulate situation of concurrent build across several Maven processes** locally on mac os, like this.

```bash
task(){
    cd "$1"; pwd;
    mvn -gs /Users/xx/settings-pre.xml clean package -Dmaven.repo.local=/Users/xx/.m2/repository -DskipTests -e -U
}

## clean local repo before concurrent build
rm -rf /Users/xx/.m2/repository

## set maven env
source  ~/newwork/script/set_maven_3.5.0.sh

## I've got 10 project with same code in current dir
## so mvn clean package will be executed in project1, project2.... project10
for d in ./*/;  do
    ## task will be exec concurrently
    task "$d" &
done
```

I've tried Takari extension（http://takari.io/book/30-team-maven.html) with Maven-3.5.0, and concurrent build failed.
[image: error log]

I've tried Maven-3.9.0 with named lock(https://maven.apache.org/resolver/maven-resolver-named-locks/index.html) but still failed.

```
mvn -gs /Users/ninan/work/apache-maven-3.8.5/conf/settings-pre.xml clean package -Dmaven.repo.local=/Users/ninan/.m6/repository -DskipTests -e -U -Daether.syncContext.named.factory=file-lock -Daether.syncContext.named.nameMapper=file-gav -Daether.syncContext.named.time=120
```

[image: error log]

1 I wonder if there is something wrong with my local test method, like I use named lock in the wrong way etc.

2 If not, what I can do to fix tis problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this a multi module build? If yes use Maven itself and don't use self crafted scripts... Maven itself can du and also in parallel... Use more recent version of maven at minimium 3.8.7 or (3.9.0)...

Comment: @khmarbaise I think the OP wants to test the new concurrency feature of Maven 3.9.0. Are there any example projects or docs for the new features of Maven 3.9.0?

Comment: The concurrency is not new in Maven it exists since Maven 3.0.0 (ca. 10 years) the part in Maven 3.9.0 are some other things ... References: https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.9.0/release-notes.html

Comment: If you have special questions please subscribe to the user mailing https://maven.apache.org/mailing-lists.html .... Also use really the most recent version of Maven (3.9.0) because the error messages implying you are using an older version (aether-imple-1.7.XX) ...

Comment: @khmarbaise I meant concurrent access to the local repository, which is a rather new feature.

Comment: I'm interested in Maven 3.9 for the same reason. Did you try 3.9.1 and check whether the wrong behaviour was a bug that has been fixed?

Answer (score -1):

I think it is bad idea to let maven do the concurrency on any level. There are reasons like:

- high risk of failure
- unclear pipeline feedback

You want the opposite: stable tests and clear results and you don't have time for playing around and experimenting. Let the testing of new Maven features be done by other people.

So you should move all the concurrency you need from Maven to pipeline itself as much as you can:

- if you need concurrent builds, create separate jobs
- if there is common maven repository, you just have to create separate Maven repository for each of them (this is painful only for the 1. time, after this Maven uses update policy so repo updates are cheap); alternatively, you would have to run jobs in the sequence
- if you need to build multimodule project, do not let Maven do it, but split it in the pipeline so that each parent module is run as separate stage (one maven invocation for one parent module)
- do not let Maven run build and test at one go: split building and testing to separate stages so that you have artifacts after build phase. These artifacts should be reused then in all later stages which do all the testing etc.
  (remember you just need POMs and artifacts in all testing stages - code is not needed anymore)
  etc.

So to sum up, do not give Maven to much work to do, but cut it into small pieces. I think you should not go in the direction you are describing.

Comment: This: `if you need to build multimodule project, do not let Maven do it, but split it in the pipeline so that each parent module is run as separate stage (one maven invocation for one parent module)`  simply wrong. Building multi modules in parallel exists since 10 years+ and works for even builds up-to 3000+ modules (-T xxx) ...

Comment: Question: `do not let Maven run build and test at one go: split building and testing to separate stages so that you have artifacts after build phase.`. why ?

Comment: Building multi modules in parallel works in Maven. It is just bad practice to use it in pipeline because of the reason I was mentioning about: unclear feedback. In my production pipeline I have 150+ modules grouped under about 15 main modules developed by 6 teams. We need to know within seconds which main module failed.

If you have tiny project it might work for you without splitting modules into stages.

Comment: As for separate build stage:
- you need to have clear feedback in the pipeline if this is build that failed or test that failed
- you need to create build artifact as soon as possible: and this is possible just after aplication is built

Comment: Unclear feedback? You will get the information in Jenkins as well other ci systems like drone, woodpecker or consource-ci which shows exactly which modules have failures and also the test will show exactly the result... I've done a. lot of times... And bad practice Hm... Ok... it's up to you....

Comment: Separte build stages?? Hm... interesting... the tests will be reported and if the build failed you ci should report that in an appropriate way because... Jenkins etc. do that?...

Comment: Yes, everything separated. This also relates to all log files. They exist as separate artifacts and are easier to examine in case of failure. This is just a good practice I recommend. But you are the king in your kingdom and of course you can do what you like.

Comment: @khmarbaise I do not support the solutions in this answer, but I must admit that it would be nicer if you could not just run `mvn deploy` and get a huge output, but if you could run it in different stages in your CI. It would make the output much cleaner, if you e.g. could have a `test` stage in GitLab CI that only runs the tests.